# Backup Software for OSX and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, backup

i am looking for current backup software that i can use on a mac and a windows machine. I found a lot of old tools. CrashPlan looks really like what i am looking for, but the hard disk back ups are in a non readable format. And thats the key. I am looking for something, where i can make human readable backups to a hard disk in my network from windows and osx!

I searched a lot through the web, but i could not find any promising software, which has an attractive UI and works like i want to.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By "human readable" I assume you mean that that files are not compressed or encrypted but are just copied in the same directory hierarchy they have in on the backed up computers. If so this requirement is at odds with what most people would consider good policy, which is why you don't find products that do this.

**Compression:** Typically you want multiple backup copies. What if a disk fails while you are doing a backup in which case both the backup and original are suspect? That's why you need at least 2 backup copies, perhaps more if a user finds they threw away the wrong file and wants to go back a few days in the history. You don't want to pay for the hard drive space to store all that data uncompressed so every backup scheme incorporates some kind of compression. Most also perform incremental backups so that only the changes from day to day are backed up. This saves space and backup time. The smart ones can even recognize duplicate files across your network and just include one reference to them everywhere they are used.

**Encryption:** Your backup is a gold mine of information. All of the data for your entire network is present in one place. You typically want an extra layer of protection to ensure that only trusted users can read it so most all backup programs encrypt their backups.

The needs for compression and eruption mean that most all commercial backup programs don't give you files on the hard drive that you can read without help. However, the good ones do provide a nice UI to browse what you have backed up from within their tool and pull out the individual file or backups as needed.

If what you really want is something to keep exact copies of your directories on a backup computer you may want to look for options for disk or file "synchronization" instead of backup. I found [this](http://mac-sync-software-review.toptenreviews.com/) review of Mac sync software.

For what its worth, I had fairly good luck with [Retrospect](http://www.retrospect.com/) for backup.

Comment: FWIW, Apple's Time Machine backup software makes what I'd call human-readable backups, but of course it doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a good solution for you: http://www.digistor.com/REWIND-Archiving-Software-for-PC-and-MAC

Archiving software for PC and Mac with a nice UI. The file system is readable by humans on both platforms, and they also include a Restore utility launching directly from the archive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Duplicati (https://www.duplicati.com) It's open source and you still need duplicati to read the backups but at least it is available for both Windows and Mac.